# On JavaScript click event Content of my class is not applied to the html <p>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting JavaScript class to the p, so it should change a colour when it's clicked, here is `<p>` element:

```
<p class="classItem"></p>
```

Here is `classItem` css class:

```
.classItem {
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #3266cc;
        border-radius: 2px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 14px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    }
```

And there you can see background color(#3266cc) - blue, I want to change it to red on a click, so I created css class

```
.activeClassItem {
        background-color: red!important;
    }
```

And on javascript I said, when I click this item let's apply also activeClassItem class, so it will set a colour of background to red, and class is really applied but colour is not changed:

```
$("body").on("click", ".classItem", function () {
            $(".activeClassItem").removeClass("activeClassItem");
            $(this).addClass("activeClassItem");
});
```

When I inspect window, class is there:

```
<p class="classItem activeClassItem"></p>
```

So guys, even if Class is applied I can not see changed background unfortunatelly...

Any kind of help is awesome,
Thanks

Comment: Works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/dh2275ov/

Comment: please check if you have included jquery
beacuse your same code is working demo here https://codepen.io/moghya/pen/aYyaPq

Comment: Is there a space between the red and !important? I.e. red[]!important;

Comment: @Noface please pay attention while editing ... you added a snippet and made his code working but the OP clearly said the code is not working fine so there is somthing missing and this is not the full code. So please don't automatically convert code to snippet

Comment: oh sorry about that

Comment: @Noface Interesting fact is class is applied, but there is not CSS applied to my row, class is there but my row is not changing colour to red.. interesting

Comment: maybe you have more code you are not showing here

Comment: @Anthonus Long ago, there were browsers that handled `!important` incorrectly if there wasn't a space before it. But that is no longer the case.

Comment: @MrLister (not Mr. Mister? :): Yes I figured it out, but still for best practices our software enforces the space. I think the space is still a good thing.

Comment: @Noface Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eyho7sko/4/

Comment: @Noface Does not matter, class is applied to paragraph but css content is not..

Comment: your issue is the css is invalid ?

Comment: your code works fine, the problem is you still did not show all your code in this question and wasted everyones time with simply invalid css. In your jsfiddle, which should actually be a code snippet, you have a css declaration without an opening bracket. therefore the class `activeClassItem` is not defined in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example , if still the issue persist , please consider testing with another browser or try to update your browser

```js
$("body").on("click", ".classItem", function () {
            $(".activeClassItem").removeClass("activeClassItem");
            $(this).addClass("activeClassItem");
});
```

```css
.classItem {
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #3266cc;
        border-radius: 2px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 14px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    }
    .activeClassItem{
    background-color:red !important
    
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p class="classItem"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: no need to answer by "YOur code is working fine, you simply forget the jQuery" ... this is not answer, add a comment instead

Comment: where it doest state that ? i dont remeber reading it in the rule of the site

Comment: I never said it's a rule ;) it's only me  .. I THINK an answer to simply say "your code is working fine" is not an answer but you are free of course.

Comment: i personaly dont care about your personal opinion i care about what the rule say and that's it :)

Comment: i also personaly don't care if you care or not about my personal opinion :) I am simply justifying my downvote as i don't like free downvoting ;)

Comment: I dont like freedown voting either , and i dont down vote people just because of my personal opinion regarding their answers

Comment: i have a plenty of reason for this downvotes if you want more : if you read the question at the end you will see clearly `When I inspect window, class is there:` --> this means his code is working since the class is there so i don't think the issue is with the jquery so i don't think you read the question untill the end

Comment: ah when it come to this , you're right having the class already in place justify a working Jquery, and yes i didnt read the bottom part of his question , i did edit my answer acordinly

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I don't understand what have you done here? Just copy and paste my code and you said it's working example, I wondering why that code does not work in my case...

Comment: @billy_56 check update your browser or try using a diffrent browser

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I did that before I posted question here, there is some reason why css from my class is not applied, class is  there but nothing from a class is applied..